# craco causes yarn build to fail due to "Cannot find module 'environment'. TS2307"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, environment, craco

I installed and configured craco following the [official README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) and the [medium article "My Awesome Custom React Environment Variables Setup"](https://blog.usejournal.com/my-awesome-custom-react-environment-variables-setup-8ebb0797d8ac). I did

- `sudo yarn global upgrade create-react-app`
- `create-react-app craco-getting-started`
- `yarn add react-scripts typescript @types/react @types/react-dom`

And created the necessary files

`public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Craco getting started</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/App.tsx`:

```
import React from "react"

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>Hello world!</div>
  }
}

export { App };
```

`src/index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { App } from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and added

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

to `package.json`.

So far, so boilerplate. The app starts with `yarn start` and displays "Hello world!".

Now, I'm configuring craco by creating `src/environments/development.ts` with

```
export default {
  isProduction: false,
  name: "development"
};
```

and `src/environments/production.ts` with

```
export default {
  isProduction: true,
  name: "production"
};
```

as well as `craco.config.js` with content

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function({ env, paths }) {
  return {
    webpack: {
      alias: {
        environment: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'environments', process.env.CLIENT_ENV)
      }
    },
  };
};
```

and installing `craco` with `yarn add @craco/craco --dev` and `cross-env` with `yarn add cross-env`.

Now, if I want to use the environment reference to access `environment.someKey` for example in `App` I need to add `import environment from "environment";` in `src/App.tsx`, but that causes `yarn build` and `yarn start` to fail due to

```
> yarn build
yarn run v1.21.1
$ cross-env CLIENT_ENV=production craco build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

/mnt/data/home/examples/craco/craco-getting-started/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in /mnt/data/home/examples/craco/craco-getting-started/src/App.tsx(2,25):
Cannot find module 'environment'.  TS2307

    1 | import React from "react"
  > 2 | import environment from "environment";
      |                         ^
    3 | 
    4 | class App extends React.Component {
    5 | 


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How can I use this created setup?

I'm providing a SSCCE at https://gitlab.com/krichter-sscce/craco-getting-started which contains no additional information, but allows to reproduce the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `@craco/craco` the `package.json` scripts need to be updated to

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "CLIENT_ENV=development craco start",
    "build": "CLIENT_ENV=production craco build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The medium article ([My Awesome Custom React Environment Variables Setup](https://medium.com/@robertsavian/my-awesome-custom-react-environment-variables-setup-8ebb0797d8ac)) you followed have some steps missing

Apart from steps mentioned in the article, you have to follow below steps.

1. Create an environment.d.ts file in your project inside src folder.
2. Declare the environment module, by pasting below code in newly created file

   ```
   declare module "environment" {
         import baseEnv from "environments/base";
         const value: ReturnType<typeof baseEnv>;

         export default value;
       }
   ```
3. Go to tsconfig.json file
4. Paste the below code snippet under compilerOptions object

   "paths": {
   "environments": ["environments"]
   }

And That's all. Now re-run your server!!!!

For working example you can refer the [repo provided in the same medium article](https://github.com/codeBelt/Custom-Environment-Variables-Setup/tree/master/create-react-app).